# What database should I use for a social media app?

Tags: android, database, mongodb, social-networks

I am planning on developing a social media app but have no idea what database to use. I have been learning to develop *android* apps and the databases that I have used so far are only SQLite and Firebase Realtime Database. I understand that SQLite is a local database and not the right database for a social media app. Firebase Realtime Database, on the other hand, can be used to build a social media app but I have heard that some problems may occur if Firebase Realtime Database handles a lot of users.

I have been thinking about MongoDB as from what I heard, it can handle millions of users. There are things like MongoDB Stitch, I am planning to use that one but I wonder if it is the right database to use for such an app? or is there any better database?

Answer (score 1):

For the past few years in our company we have switched almost exclusively to using MongoDB as go-to database for virtually all our developments. It is schema-less, JSON-style database, where documents stored in the database can have varying sets of fields, with different types for each field. It is very easy to use, it's fast, it's very easily readable for debugging and validation purposes, and there are great indexing and search tools available (like Elasticsearch) that helps to speed-up the database for scalable projects.

Answer (score 1):

Today is the rise of popularity of NoSQL databases, such as Firebase Realtime Database and MongoDB etc.. both best for web or mobile development but I much recommend to use **MongoDB** instead of Firebase.

And then I recommend to use **Offline First Approach** for your social media app wherein you need build an application's core features to function with or without an internet connection. For this approach I recommend to use [**PouchDB**](https://pouchdb.com/) to sync your data to your user browsers and they can use  your app even without internet. But along with PouchDB you need to sync your data to a database, based from their [documentation](https://pouchdb.com/faq.html) you can only sync your PouchDB data to **CouchDB**, **Cloudant**, and **PouchDB Server**.

So I like to recommend combination of **PouchDB with MongoDB** but I still doubt if it works, read this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384803/using-pouchdb-with-mongodb). Or **PouchDB with CouchDB/PouchDB Server**.

Try the following also read this for additional database combination:

- https://www.gangboard.com/blog/what-database-does-facebook-use
- https://www.techworm.net/2013/05/what-database-actually-facebook-uses.html
- https://www.quora.com/What-do-big-websites-like-Facebook-Google-Twitter-and-LinkedIn-use-for-their-database-What-would-be-the-pros-and-cons-of-what-they-use-and-why